# Binding Angular <object> svg data property

Tags: angular, html, data-binding

I tried many attempts to bind SVG data path but no one seems to work.
Here my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let icon of icons"">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" [data]="icon.path"></object>
</div>
```

Ts:

```
    public icons = [ {name: '...', path: '/svg/...svg', href: 'https://...'},..,];
```

I tried to use [data], data = "{{...}}", and so on.
I am not getting any particular error, just I am not able to visualize any image. I am using object tag to have the possibility to change the "fill" property dynamically. I tried to directly write the path within the data property of the object tag and it works correctly. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

What about the `attr.data`?

```
<div *ngFor="let icon of icons"">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" [attr.data]="icon.path"></object>
</div>
```

as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets).

EDIT:

Would be better to sanitize the path before.

```
<!-- COMPONENT -->

    import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
      ...
    })
    export class SvgComponent {

      private sanitizer;

      constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService ) {
        this.sanitizer = sanitizer;    
      }

      svgURL(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
      }
    }

<!-- TEMPLATE -->

    <div *ngFor="let icon of icons"">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" [attr.data]="svgURL(icon.path)"></object>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, already tried but without any success. I am getting  the following error: Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Comment: Solved by using that solutions [link](https://filipmolcik.com/error-unsafe-value-used-in-a-resource-url-context/) and attr.data.

Comment: Perfect, few moments ago i've updated my answer with more or less the same solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Angular will block the URL due to security issues.
You can tell Angular the URL is safe.

Create a new `@Pipe` as described below and use it in the template

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeUrl' })
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform 
{
  public constructor(private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(unsafeUrl: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(unsafeUrl);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" [data]="getUrl() | safeUrl"></object>
```